# Safecracker entries not showing in front end

Tags: safecracker, entries

Pretty new to EE, I am creating a site similar to desert island discs - but for crisps for a friend and as part of my uni assignment.

I'm using EE 2.5 and Safecracker 2.1. I have created the safecracker form based on this tutorial by Ryan White http://www.venveo.com/articles/view/understanding-safecracker-for-expressionengine.

Now the form works a charm from the front end. This is the setup:user_entries. Status group with status Pending created and assigned to the group. In members I have created an annonymous user and assigned access to the above channel to publish from front end (status still pending). This is all good.

I have a template group called entries and inside this I have the user_entries template where the form code resides. I also have a confirmation template to redirect users upo successful submission.

Now every time I test this, an entry is created - but in the pages section, which is fine. I can go there publish the page and all is good. What I can't figure out is how do I output all the new entries (after status change to Open) on the front end to another page called say Previous entries or similar.

Here is my code for the Safecracker form:

```
{embed="includes/html_head"}
<body>


<!-- Super Container for entire site -->
{embed="includes/masthead"}
<!-- Super Container -->
<div class="super-container full-width">

    <!-- 960 Container -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- CONTENT -->
        <div class="eleven columns content">        
        <h2 class="title"><span>Submit your 8 choices!</span></h2>  

<!--============SAFECRACKER STUFF GOES RIGHT HERE=============-->
                    {exp:safecracker
  channel="user_entries"
  return="entries/confirmation"
  include_jquery="no"
  logged_out_member_id="2"
  rules:your_name="required"
  rules:choice_number_1="required"
  rules:choice_number_2="required"
  rules:choice_number_3="required"
  rules:choice_number_4="required"
  rules:choice_number_5="required"
  rules:choice_number_6="required"
  rules:choice_number_7="required"
  rules:choice_number_8="required"
  rules:title="required"
}
<br class="clearfix" />
            <hr />

<h3 class="feature">
    <label><strong>First please tell us your name</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="your_name" value="{your_name}"/>
  </h3>
 <br class="clearfix" />
            <hr />
<h3 class="feature">
    <label><strong>Give your choice a memorable name</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="title" value="{title}"/>
  </h3>

<fieldset class="five columns alpha aside">

  <!--Choice one code-->
  <h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 1</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_1"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 1 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_1_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 1 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="" name="choice_1_image" />
</fieldset>


<!--====Choice twocode-->
<fieldset class="five columns omega aside">
  <h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 2</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_2"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 2 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_2_description"/>
  </p>
  <br />
    <label>Choice 2 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="button green" name="choice_2_image"/>

  </fieldset>



<!--===============Choice three code-->
<fieldset class="five columns alpha aside">

<h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 3</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_3"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 3 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_3_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 3 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="button green" name="choice_3_image"/>

</fieldset>


<!--====Choice four code-->
<fieldset class="five columns omega aside">
  <h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 4</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_4"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 4 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_4_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 4 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="button green" name="choice_4_image"/>  
  </fieldset>



<!--===============Choice five code-->
<fieldset class="five columns alpha aside">

<h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 5</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_5"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 5 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_5_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 5 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="button green" name="choice_5_image"/>
</fieldset>


<!--====Choice six code-->
<fieldset class="five columns omega aside">
  <h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 6</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_6"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 6 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_6_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 6 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="button green" name="choice_6_image"/>
  </fieldset>


<!--===============Choice seven code-->
<fieldset class="five columns alpha aside">

<h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 7</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_7"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 7 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_7_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Choice 7 image</label>
    <input type="file" class="button green" name="choice_7_image"/>
</fieldset>


<!--====Choice eight code-->
<fieldset class="five columns omega aside">
  <h5>
    <label><strong>Choice number 8</strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_number_8"/>
  </h5>
  <p>
    <label>Choice 8 description</label>
    <input type="text" class="text" name="choice_8_description"/>
  </p>
<br />
    <label>Have an image for Choice 8 image?</label>
    <input type="file" class="button green" name="choice_8_image"/>
  </fieldset>  
<!==============End the fieldsets here for the 8 choices-->
<br class="clearfix" />
            <hr />
  <p>
  <input type="submit" class="button yellow" value="Submit your choices now!" />
</p>
   <br class="clear" />
{/exp:safecracker}

            <br class="clearfix" />
            <hr />

        </div>  
        <!-- /CONTENT -->

        <!-- SIDEBAR -->
        <div class="five columns sidebar">

            {embed="includes/sidebar"}      <!-- /SIDEBAR -->

    </div>
    <!-- /End 960 Container -->

</div>
<!-- /End Super Container -->


<!-- ============================================== -->


{footer}    
<!-- End Document
================================================== -->
</body>
</html>
```

I shall be eternally grateful to any body who can help me with this issue. Please remember I'm  new to EE so go gentle.

Many thanks

Ilir

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="user_entries" limit="8" status="pending|open"}
  <h4 class="title">
    <span>
      This is the choice {title} made by {your_name} on {entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"}
    </span>
  </h4>
  <ol>
    <li class={first|second|third|fourth|fifth|sixth|seventh|last}>
      <h5>{choice_number_1}</h5>
      <p class="align-left">{choice_1_description}</p>
      <img class="align-left" src="{choice_1_image}"/>
    </li>
  </ol>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Can you post what your template looks like for displaying the entries from that channel on the front end?

Comment: 'code'{exp:channel:entries channel="user_entries" limit="8" status="pending|open"}
  <h4 class="title"><span>This is the choice {title} made by {your_name} on {entry_date format="%F %d, %Y"}</span></h4> 
    <ol>
    <li class={first|second|third|fourth|fifth|sixth|seventh|last}>
    <h5>{choice_number_1}</h5>
    <p class="align-left">{choice_1_description}</p>
    <img class="align-left" src="{choice_1_image}"/></li>
 </ol>
  {/exp:channel:entries} 
  </div> 
  <!-- /CONTENT -->
  
  <!-- SIDEBAR -->
  <div class="five columns sidebar">'code'

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `dynamic="no"`and see if that changes things.

`{exp:channel:entries channel="user_entries" limit="8" status="pending|open" dynamic="no"}Entry Title: {title}<br>Entry ID: {entry_id}<br>Choice 1 Description: {choice_1_description}<br><hr>{/exp:channel:entries}`

Comment: The problem (or one of a number of problems) I have is also the I have 3 x 8 custom fields for each entry, because users need to make 8 choices I thought I would need to create the form with 3 fields for each entry, so one for Choice name, 1 for choice description and one for file upload so users can upload an image. What I don't know how to do is what code do I put where to display the entries in the front end, at the moment they go to the confirmation page which thanks users for the entry. How do I then display the entries as an admin from CP to display on the site once approved?

Comment: First, can you confirm that the user-submitted data is being saved in an entry in the user_entries channel? Do they show up correctly in EE on the backend?

Comment: Yes they do, apart from the images. They are not showing although they are being uploaded to the directory I specified.

Comment: oops my mistake, the images are actually not being uploaded to the directory specified, just checked this!

Comment: try the exact code above and see what it does.

Comment: what the above does is create the title of entry then a description then the rest of the title entries are displayed. This is probably to do with the loop using the {title} and then at {choice_1_description} the loop stops to render the description, then continues with the rest of the Entries titles. But I want it to loop through all 8 titles and 8 description fields, AND the 8 image fields. Progress none the less, thanks @Stephen C

Comment: Updated the code. Try it. If the description is not showing, can you confirm that that particular entry actually has a description in EE?

Comment: Woohoo that works. This is what I get now:Entry Title: Ilir’s crisps of choice
Entry ID: 18
Choice 1 Description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printi industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged."   That's fantastic. can I get rid of the entry id? Or how would I go about turning the entry ID to something like Choice N# 1, choice N# 2, etc. Thanks Stephen

Comment: Your full reply didn't come through. Maybe add it to your original answer above so it's in a larger viewing area.

Comment: Woohoo that works. This is what I get now:Entry Title: Ilir’s crisps of choice Entry ID: 18 Choice 1 Description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printi industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged." That's fantastic. can I get rid of the entry id? Or how would I go about turning the entry ID to something like Choice N# 1, choice N# 2, etc.

Comment: One other question please if I may? How would I go about making it so that the results are displayed in the order they are submitted? So e.g. Because in the front end I present the user with 24 fields, 3 for each choice they make, how then do I translate this into the View template? The loop does its magic, I get that, but I need this to somehow create a list of choice 1, 2, 3, 4 etc....Am I being dense here?

Comment: It is probably best illustrated if I show you a screenshot of the frontend entry: http://grab.by/lNBs